FFMPEG > The transcoded video contains insufficient number of frames
I am trying to transcode the videos (which I receive via the javascript media recorder in streaming mode by telephone) to use the VP9 codec
and also to resolve concerns about the duration of these videos,
the command ffmpeg that i use is this:
ffmpeg -i video-input -map 0 -crf 40 -deadline realtime -threads 8 -cpu-used 8 -b:v 0 -movflags +faststart -row-mt 1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 video-output;

The command works for most videos, except for certain videos, the transcoded video contains very few frames compared to the input video,
the input video has a size of 29MB and the output has only 80KB.
ffmpeg does not return error messages
The Output of fffmpeg command for a unsuccessful conversion:
    ffmpeg version 5.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -march=x86-64-v2 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 ' --extra-cflags=' -I/usr/include/rav1e' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --enable-chromaprint --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsmbclient --enable-version3 --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3 --enable-vapoursynth --enable-libvpx --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-avfilter --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-lto --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/video-input':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso5hlsf
    creation_time   : 2024-03-17T19:39:41.000000Z
  Duration: 1988:25:02.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1280x720, 0 kb/s, 0.0001 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-03-17T19:39:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f944aa40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9479500] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94a7340] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94d5980] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9503fc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9531e00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9560440] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f958ea80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f95a1600] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9554f80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94fe4c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9588440] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f952e340] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9462700] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9492540] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94c0380] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94d6d80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9548d00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94ec540] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9573580] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9519380] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f944d2c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f947b140] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94ab740] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94d6d80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9548d00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94ec540] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9573580] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f9519380] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f944d2c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f947b140] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55e0f943c5c0] [swscaler @ 0x55e0f94ab740] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x55e0f80371c0] v1.9.0
Output #0, webm, to '/video-output.webm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso5hlsf
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: vp9, yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x1280, q=2-31, 0.0001 fps, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-03-17T19:39:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=471 speed=   0x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55e0f8010cc0] DTS 14421 < 14422 out of order
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=40.0 Lsize=      38kB time=02:43:52.83 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=725 speed=1.22e+04x    
video:37kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.819037%

The Output of fffmpeg command for a successful conversion:
ffmpeg version 5.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -march=x86-64-v2 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 ' --extra-cflags=' -I/usr/include/rav1e' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3 --enable-vapoursynth --enable-libvpx --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-avfilter --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-lto --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/video-input':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso5hlsf
    creation_time   : 2024-01-19T08:29:28.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:19.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9967 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1280x720, 9964 kb/s, 30.05 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-01-19T08:29:28.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2ce9680] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d18100] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d46740] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d74580] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2da2bc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2dd1200] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2ce9680] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d00940] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d2f000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2db5d00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d89f00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d5bb00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d592c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2de3d80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d00940] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d2f000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2db5d00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d89f00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d592c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2de3d80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d00940] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d2f000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2db5d00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x5624f2cdb900] [swscaler @ 0x5624f2d89f00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x5624f1b5e400] v1.9.0
Output #0, webm, to 'video-output.webm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso5hlsf
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: vp9, yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x1280, q=2-31, 30 fps, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-01-19T08:29:28.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   55 fps=0.0 q=31.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=   5.1kbits/s speed=1.94x    
frame=  117 fps=114 q=35.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:03.13 bitrate=   1.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=3.06x    
frame=  160 fps=105 q=40.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:04.56 bitrate= 918.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=2.99x    
frame=  223 fps=110 q=38.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:06.66 bitrate= 629.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=3.28x    
frame=  288 fps=113 q=40.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:08.83 bitrate= 949.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=2 speed=3.48x    
frame=  350 fps=115 q=40.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:10.93 bitrate= 767.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=2 speed=3.59x    
frame=  412 fps=116 q=40.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:13.00 bitrate= 806.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=2 speed=3.66x    
frame=  476 fps=118 q=40.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:15.13 bitrate= 692.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=2 speed=3.74x    
frame=  532 fps=117 q=40.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:17.00 bitrate= 616.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=3.74x    
frame=  582 fps=116 q=40.0 Lsize=    2098kB time=00:00:19.50 bitrate= 881.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed= 3.9x    
video:2093kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.227047%

Can you help me please ?
Thanks a lot

While ffmpeg may not report errors, it is certain to report something. Please provide a complete example output, maybe for both successful and unsuccessful conversion.

I added the output of the ffmpeg command for unsuccessful conversion, thank you!

The input video's metadata already looks pretty suspicious. For comparison, a successful conversion would be very helpful.

I added the output of the ffmpeg command for a successful conversion, thank you for your help !

The issue is probably related to the input video because FFmpeg reports: Duration: 1988:25:02.86, 0 kb/s 0.0001 fps. You may try using two commands: ffmpeg -i video-input -c:v copy tmp.264 and ffmpeg -i tmp.264 -map 0 -crf 40 -deadline realtime -threads 8 -cpu-used 8 -b:v 0 -movflags +faststart -row-mt 1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 video-output. Without the input video we can only guess the solution. Please consider sharing the input video (using Google Drive for example).

Thank you for your proposition, When i run  ffmpeg -i video-input -c:v copy tmp.264, i have this error : [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55f5c85417c0] DTS 0 < 401 out of order [h264 @ 0x55f5c8570000] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 401 >= 0 .... 

Usually it's just a warning. Try adding -fflags +igndts before the -i. Without the input video, it's just guessing...
